# How to stop foreach if record already available in database

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to stop a foreach loop if a record already exit in the database and show alert message.

```
  angular.foreach(data, function (value, key) {

                if ($scope.serviceNameAttribute == value.name) {
                    count++;
                    alert("Attribute already exists");
                    return false;
                }
                if ($scope.displayNameAttribute == value.name) {
                    count++;
                    alert("Attribute already exists");
                    return false;
                }
                if ($scope.serviceNameAttribute + ' ' + $scope.displayNameAttribute == value.name) {
                    count++;
                    alert("Attribute already exists");
                    return false;
                }

            });
```

Please find the code attached, here after showing the alert message, if duplicate records are available in the table, it is showing the alert message multiple times

Comment: use `break` to stop lopping https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break. And try to use Google first, it is a good helper

Comment: As one answer of the question posted above this comment states, you're better off using a native for loop instead of a foreach loop. It's faster and breakable!

Comment: @Jelly, break is not working in js file. And i have also tried using the native for loop but its not working, i would appreciate if you could please convert the code in 'for' loop.